# template_preprocess_html(&$vars) dynamic code

Tags: theming

I have an html template variable called "sitepage" that needs to be set by a module based on node relationships.

Is there a way to set html.tpl variables from a module?

```
function dc_preprocess_html(&$vars)
{
    $vars['sitepage'] = '/*Insert Business Logic as described below*/';
}
```

The logic for what the sitepage should be is as followed:

1. If we are on a car model or car make page then find the car make node and check to see if there is a node reference to an Advertiser node.
2. Using the advertiser node, check the field "field_sponsor_site_page" to determine the site page

I can easily do this in the module code, but need to do this so I can put the variable in html.tpl.php

The way it works now:

I have 2 pages in play:

1. Car Detail Page: `model/[Car Make Node FIELD_COLLECTION_ID]`
2. List Cars of a particular model: `makes/[Car Make Node Id]`

A car make node has a node reference to Advertiser. The advertiser has a sitepage that needs to be inserted into html.tpl.php in both cases based on this business logic

Comment: Really not following you here, you've already answered the question in the question...you use template_preprocess_html. Assuming your module is called dc all you need to do is fill in the 'easy' business logic part and you're done. What have I missed?

Comment: The code for the business logic is in a module called dc_car_guide but I need to set a variabled $sitepage in html.tpl.php I will update question with more details

Comment: Do you realise modules can also implement preprocess hooks in exactly the same way? Just call the function `dc_car_guide_preprocess_html`...

Comment: that seems to work, but It seem the module preprocess_html is called before the template preprocess. How is the order determined?

Comment: Yes hooks for modules are always run first. Why would you need it to run after the theme layer?

Answer (score 0):

try

```
hook_module_implements_alter()
```

to alter the hooks order

Comment: How is order determined anyways?

Comment: its based on the module name acctually ...

Comment: It's based on a few factors not just module name. There's a question on the site somewhere that explains it really well ill try to dig it out...

Comment: http://drupal.org/node/110238

Good call for a better search, cheers